# Custom UITableView updating appropriately with every label and UIImage, except one - using Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` that's populated by `NSFetchedResultsController` and `Core Data` where the user adds in information into another view, saves and then the `UITableView` updates.

Everything is working with the exception of one `UIImageView` in the custom cell.

The user adds in a name, event, sub-event, date, status and optionally a note in another view that's called modally from this `UITableViewController` with a button in the `NavigationBar`.

**Problem**

The notes `UITextView` has a default value of "Additional Notes :" and I have configured it so that if a user starts typing, it removes that text and if the user taps in that cell but doesnt type anything, it just goes back to "Additional Notes :". If the user adds in a note to the entry, the `UITableViewCell` is made to display a "pin" image. That works. If the user does not add in a note, there's no PIN image. However, in the scenario below, the pin is still displayed.

**Broken Scenario**

1) Add a new entry without a note. `UITableViewCell` does not display PIN. -- Correct.

2) Edit entry to include note. When saved, the `UITableViewCell` displays a PIN -- Correct.

3) Edit entry again to remove note (which defaults back to the "Additional Notes :" text.) When saved, the PIN is still displayed in the custom cell. -- Incorrect.

4) If you close the app from the multi-tasking, and then re-launch the app, the PIN is then not displayed on that cell.

So it's a case of refreshing.

Here's my cell code:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    TimelineTableViewCell *customCell = (TimelineTableViewCell *)cell;
    Transaction *transaction = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    customCell.nameLabel.text = transaction.whoBy.name;
    customCell.amountLabel.text = transaction.item.amount;
    customCell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    customCell.amountLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Events and Subevents
    if ([transaction.subevent.title length] > 0)
    {
        customCell.eventLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", transaction.occasion.title, transaction.subevent.title];
        customCell.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else
    {
        customCell.eventLabel.text = transaction.occasion.title;
        customCell.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    // Setting up the cells text and custom circle status images
    if ([transaction.wasReceived boolValue])
    {
        UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 14, 15)];
        dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Greendotwithshadow"];
        [customCell addSubview:dot];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *dot = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 14, 15)];
        dot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Reddotwithshadow.png"];
        [customCell addSubview:dot];
    }

    if (![transaction.notes isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "] && [transaction.notes length] > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"This is a test service announcement");
        UIImageView *pin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 30, 24, 25)];
        pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
        [customCell addSubview:pin];

    }

    UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    customCell.selectedBackgroundView = customColorView;

}
```

It's the last if statement there thats not working as it should be. However, the other if statements are working. If I create an entry with the status "Received", it adds a Red dot to the cell. If I edit that entry to "Given", a green dot is shown instead when the UITableView is reloaded. I don't understand why the pin image is not acting as it should though.

In my viewWillAppear, I have no reload data, but at the same time, I tried:

```
NSError *error;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[self.timelineTableView reloadData];
```

with no difference.

The Notes is a `UITextView` in the entry and the Status is a `UISegmentedControl`.

In the save method of the edit entry, this is my code for the Notes and Status:

```
self.selectedTransaction.wasReceived = @(self.editingIsReceivedSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0);

self.selectedTransaction.notes = self.editingNotesTextView.text;
```

The image for the status acts perfectly, but the notes does not.

Any thoughts or suggestion with this would really be appreciated.

Comment: You should remove the pin image in else of `if (![transaction.notes isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "] && [transaction.notes length] > 0)` if pin exists. And not related to this question : what happens if user types "Additional Notes: " as note.

Comment: Thanks @Akhilrajtr - how would I remove the pin? I mean, what code should I use.. is there an equivalent "addSubview" code to remove? Also, if the user actually adds in "Additional Notes: " exactly like that, it should not contain a note..

Comment: If `TimelineTableViewCell` has a xib, then add dot and pin imageviews in xib and connect with IBOutlet. Then you can easily access them via properties of `customCell` and change image or show/hide. So each alloc init and addsubview can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
UIImageView *pin;
if (![transaction.notes isEqualToString:@"Additional Notes: "] && [transaction.notes length] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"This is a test service announcement");
    if ([customCell viewWithtag:8888]) {
        pin = (UIImageView *)[customCell viewWithtag:8888];
    } else {
        pin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 30, 24, 25)];
        pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
        pin.tag = 8888;
        [customCell addSubview:pin];
    }
} else {
     if ([customCell viewWithtag:8888]) {
        pin = (UIImageView *)[customCell viewWithtag:8888];
        [pin removeFromSuperview];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Akhilrajtr, that worked like a charm! I slightly adjusted the code to basically just put the if statement showing the view and the else removing it with the tag, but your assistance was what got me there along with your code! Thanks again